# In a system of two local processes communicating with each other over HTTP, how can I enforce using the same connection throughout the session?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, connection

I have access only to client-side code, so if there is a way, then it has to take place there.

I've figured that I should use a single global `XMLHttpRequest` object, initialized as follows:

1. `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();`
2. `request.setRequestHeader("keep-alive",true);`
3. `request.setRequestHeader("keep-alive-max",1000000);`
4. `request.setRequestHeader("keep-alive-timeout",1000000);`

Number 3 means that 1 million times should suffice for this session.

Number 4 means that 1 million seconds should suffice for this session.

However, the code above doesn't seem to achieve the purpose:

The session is executed on localhost port 8080, and when I observe it using (Windows command) `netstat -aon | find "8080"`, I see that different connections are created and destroyed throughout the session.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't believe that XMLHttpRequest gives you any control over session handling. Also, how did you come up with keep-alive-max and keep-alive-timeout?

Comment: @JulianReschke: Found it in various HTTP descriptions online (but of course, totally unsure of it). Do you have any suggestion in that case?

Comment: don't use them, if they are not defined in a relevant spec.

Comment: @JulianReschke: Thank you. Would you also happen to have any constructive suggestions here (i.e., on top of things that I shouldn't do, things that I should)?

Comment: As I said in my first comment; I do not believe XMLHttpRequest gives you that level of control. Maybe you could elaborate why that is a problem?